# How to manage memory with ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have seen in many sites, that when using ARC you still need to nullify arrays and some things, but I thought it was automatic... so I have a couple of questions:

- When do I have to care about memory and what should I do?
- When, for example, I have a 2 window app (main window+2nd window) and I call the second window and it fills an array, when it closes to return to the main window must I put array=nil? Or does that ARC automatically when the window closes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe ARC does it automatically. If it doesn't, then I have some work to do.

Comment: I thought the same, and now I have some random strdup memory leaks.. :(

Comment: You don't have to set instance variables to nil in your `dealloc`..
ARC will automatically release these ivars on `dealloc`

Comment: Note that ARC is only concerned with Objective C objects. If you manually allocate memory via e.g. `malloc()`, you'll have to deallocate it yourself.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing that out! The poster might want to read: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC is great progress in the Objective-c development, but you have to be really careful with the memory management, even when you use ARC.

I suggest that you watch the [WWDC 2011 video about ARC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=323) to do a great use of this feature, because you need to watch some details to really do not waste the memory of the device.

The most important points to you get the best of ARC, is to make sure you does not have circular references, such as one controller reference another controller, and both have strong references, when you think you destroyed one controller, the other will retain it, and then you will have no memory freed by it.

The other important point, is that you need to be sure that you told the compiler that you will not need more an object, this is why you need to set the array to nil, so the compiler will just add the command to release the array, because ARC is just Automatic Reference Counting, and it is done by the compiler, and not in runtime. Now your compiler add the release calls to you.

So answering your points:

1 - You always need to care about memory, because arc has some rules that must be obey, like set to nil the object that you are not using anymore.

2 - In your example you will need to take care about some points, first you will need to be sure that you does not have an reference to your second window, and also you will need to set to nil your array, because Objective-c has not garbage collector, just now the reference counting is not explicit anymore.

Answer (score 2):

By nullifying an array you are telling ARC that you no longer need that array and it is safe for iOS to clean it up. It is also good practice to nullify an array because checking against nil is important for many forms of iOS programming.

Yes you can allow ARC to handle everything but you can also allow iOS to clean up memory as soon as you are done with it. I would also add that appropriate nil setting statements can be a good form of self documentation.

Comment: So, although a controller is about to close and redirect to another window, it's better if I manually nullify an array, right?

Comment: That depends on where the array is declared. If it's an ivar of the second controller, it will be released automatically when the controller gets deallocated. If it's a global variable or stored in the first controller, you'll need to nullify it manually.